# How do I invoke a tesseract function from its API?

Tags: tesseract

I wanted to retrieve the font details from tesseract.I'm trying to use the Tess API to retrieve those details.But I'm not able to get the result due to some error in linkage of header files. The errors are listed in the webpage below:

http://pastebin.com/dv2QMT22

Comment: Would you please share your code ? Obviously you miss (;) somewhere !

Comment: Here is the link to see my code http://pastebin.com/PdTmLqQe @dervish